# How do I integrate this function with a change of variables?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, change-of-variable

I have the follwing problem:

> Let $$f_a(x,y)=\frac{1}{\left(\left(x+y-1\right)^2+\left(x-y+2\right)^2+1\right)^a}$$ For which $a>0$ is the function integrable.

I have just shown that $f_a$ is mesurable. Now I only need to compute $$\int_\mathbb{R}\left(\int_\mathbb{R} |f_a(x,y)|d\lambda(x)\right)d\lambda(y)$$ To do so, they give us the hint to use a change of variables and then the polar coordinates. But I somehow don't see how to do the change of variables. I thought that maybe one could first apply the polar coordinates but then I get something like $$\left|\frac{1}{\left(2r^2+2r(\cos\theta-3\sin\theta)+6\right)^a}\right|$$
Could maybe someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: The change of coordinates referred to was actually

$$\begin{cases}u = x+y-1\\v=x-y+2\end{cases} \implies J^{-1} = 2$$

which would give an integrand of

$$\iint_{\Bbb{R}^2} \frac{dudv}{2(u^2+v^2+1)^a}$$

and then change to polar coordinates after to analyze convergence.

Comment: shouldn't there be a -2? because I have the $C^1$-Diffeomorphism $\phi^{-1}(x,y)=(x+y-1,x-y+2):=(u,v)$ then $\det(D\phi^{-1})=-2$ and thus $\det(D\phi)=\frac{1}{-2}$

Comment: @Wave no - the Jacobian is always taken to be positive definite by convention since you will always set up your bounds low to high anyway. With this point of view, the minus signs from u substitution in $1$D did not matter at all since they oriented the bounds low to high for us anyway.

Comment: sorry I have never heard about such a convention, but is it wrong if i do such subsitutions with a minus? Ah oh sorry I didn't see that in the transformation formula they take the absolute value of the det.

Comment: @Wave yes it is is wrong to do it with a minus - feel free to consult any first year multivariable calculus textbook of your choice in the section on Jacobians and change of variable.

Comment: could I post the solution here if I solved it so that you could take a look?

Comment: sorry I somehow got stuck: I wanted to do a change of variabels into polar coordinates, i.e. $$\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{d\lambda(u)d\lambda(v)}{2(u^2+v^2+1)^a}=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{r}{2(r^2+1)^a} d\theta dr$$ but then I get to $$\int_0^1 \frac{\pi r}{(r^2+1)^a} dr$$

Comment: @Wave I was about to say that was correct, but think more carefully about what kind of radius would cover all of $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: is it $r\in [0,\infty)$? but then the intervall isn't compact and thus we don't know if the lesbesgue integral and the riemann integral are the same

Comment: or did I see this wrong?

Comment: @Wave that was interpreted correctly. You don't need compactness if you have positive definiteness

Comment: ah okey so I will try do do it, and send you the final solution if it would be okey for you.

Comment: In order to solve it with Riemann integrals I did it like this $$\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{r}{2(r^2+1)^a}d\lambda(\theta)d\lambda(r)=\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{r}{2(r^2+1)^a}d\theta dr$$ and then I get to $$\frac{\pi}{2} \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{y^{1-a}}{1-a}\right)$$ but this limes is smaller than infinity iff $1-a<1\Leftrightarrow a>0$. Is this correct

Comment: sorry I mean iff $1-a<0 \Leftrightarrow a>1$

Comment: @Wave yes that is correct

Comment: perfect thank you!

Comment: @Wave I hope you know about upvotes and accepting an answer if you find them satisfactory :) https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer/3287#3287

Comment: sorry, i forgot it